# Create virtual USB drive

Tags: usb

How is possible to create virtual USB drive?

I found some examples, that they included some *.iso file into mount directory.

But i would like to create empty virtual USB drive with about 4 GB volume.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS.

Thank you

Comment: You can create empty FAT images and mount them in the same way as ISO images. You can't create "virtual USB drives", though: the image will be access through a loop device, not through an USB device. But of course you can copy a FAT image to and from an USB stick.

Comment: @tomsk You may boot your linux with qemu on a rescue disk, and give it the img as a virtual usb device. But probably there are also better solutions. Next time write into your question that you want to trick some installers (because you've lost the original key for your legally bought software), so you question will be more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a virtual USB volume use the following steps:

Use [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) to create a new file:

```
fallocate -l 4000M Virtual_usb.img
```

Format it:

```
mkfs -t ext4 Virtual_usb.img
```

Create a mount point:

```
mkdir /media/usb_mount_point
```

mount it:

```
mount -t auto -o loop Virtual_usb.img /media/usb_mount_point
```

Comment: Yea, it works, but Tails Installer cannot recognize it.